# Preview table from the database

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I use fxml table and I want doing code for table from the data base, as possible more simple
Now I use code:

```
public void base(){
   private static Connection con;       
   private static Statement stat;
        con = javaconectDB.ConectDB();
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from contacts"); 

        while (rs.next()) { 
            data.add(new aWork(rs.getString("Firstname"),rs.getString("Lastname"), rs.getString("Email"),
                    rs.getString("Phone")));
                     Firstname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<aWork, String>("firstname"));
            Lastname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<aWork, String>("lastname"));
etc...
```

But this code is very big
I  found in internet this simple code

`table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToNestedList(resultSet));`

But this code don't work when I use fxml table, becouse fxml table have not code setModel. Maybe you know how I can use code described above in fxml table.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing APIs from two different UI toolkits. `setModel` method exists only for a table in Swing toolkit. JavaFX `TableView` does not have one.